# mapping associative array with another associative array

Tags: php, arrays, dictionary, associative-array

I found a way to solve my problem, but I want to see if there is any better or clear solution for this. I have two associative arrays like this:

```
$person= [
    "A" => [
            "sur" => "a",
            "fir" => "andras"
            ],
    "C" =>  [
            "sur" => "b",
            "fir" => "balint"
            ]
];
$data = [
    "A" => ["011", "012", "013"],
    "C" => ["021", "022"]
];
```

I want to map the two arrays if their keys are equal. So the result should look like this:

```
$person= [
    "A" => [
            "sur" => "a",
            "fir" => "andras",
            "tel" => ["011", "012", "013"]
            ],
    "C" =>  [
            "sur" => "b",
            "fir" => "balint",
            "tel" => ["021", "022"]
            ]
];
```

My code:

```
foreach ( array_intersect_key(array_keys($data,$person)) as $id) {
    $person[$id]['tel'] = $data[$id];
}
```

Comment: Maybe you should post your review to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: okay, i will do it. thank you!

Comment: [Cross-posted on Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/111788/9357)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method looks fine to me. For your example I'd do it like this:

```
array_walk($person, function(&$v, $k) use ($data) {
    $v['tel'] = $data[$k];
});
```

Simply because when I come back to the code months down the line I can quickly see that I am iterating and changing an array from the use of array_walk - really is personal preference I think.

Answer (score 0):

It look like that you want to loop two array with the same index ...
so try this

```
foreach ($person as $key => $value) {   
    $person[$key]['tel'] = $data[$key];         
}
var_dump($person);
```

Comment: I missed an information. I want to map only if the person and data $key match each other. The basic code (hard coding) is looks like this:
    foreach ($person as $pkey => $pvalue) {
     foreach ($data as $dkey => $dval) {
      if($dkey == $pkey) {
       $person[$pkey]["tel"] = $adat[$dkey];
      }
     }
    }